# Spring Kafka polling with @KafkaListener and listener ack-mode set as record

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm using @KafkaListener and ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory to listen to 3 kafka topics and each topic has 10 partitions. I have few questions on how this works.

```
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency(30);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        return factory;
    }
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic1", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void handleMessage(final ConsumerRecord<Object, String> arg0) throws Exception {
    }
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic2", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void handleMessage(final ConsumerRecord<Object, String> arg0) throws Exception {
    }
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic3", containerFactory="kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void handleMessage(final ConsumerRecord<Object, String> arg0) throws Exception {
    }
```

my listener.ackmode is *return* and enable.auto.commit is set to *false* and  partition.assignment.strategy: *org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor*

1) my understanding about concurrency is, since i set my concurrency (at factory level) to 30, and i have a total of 30 partitions (for all three topic together) to read from, each thread will be assigned one partition. Is my understanding correct? how does it impact if i override concurrency again inside @KafkaListener annotation?

2) When spring call the poll() method, does it poll from all three topics?

3) since i set  listener.ackmode is set to return, will it wait until all of the records that were returned in a single poll() to completed before issuing a next poll()? Also what happens if my records are taking longer than max.poll.interval.ms to process? Lets say 1-100 offsets are returned in a single poll() call and my code is only able to process 50 before max.poll.interval.ms is hit, will spring issue another poll at this time because it already hit max.poll.interval.ms? if so will the next poll() return records from offset 51?

really appreciate for your time and help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> my listener.ackmode is return

There is no such ackmode; since you don't set it on the factory, your actual ack mode is BATCH (the default). To use ack mode record (if that's what you mean), you must so configure the factory container properties.

> my understanding about concurrency is ...

Your understanding is incorrect; concurrency can not be greater than the number of partitions **in the topic with the most partitions (if a listener listens to multiple topics)**. Since you only have 10 partitions in each topic, your actual concurrency is 10.

Overriding the `concurrency` on a listener simply overrides the factory setting; you always need at least as many partitions as concurrency.

> When spring call the poll() method, does it poll from all three topics?

Not with that configuration; you have 3 concurrent containers, each with 30 consumers listening to one topic. You have 90 consumers.

If you have a single listener for all 3 topics, the poll will return records from all 3; but you still may have 20 idle consumers, depending on how the partition assignor allocates the partitions - see the logs "partitions assigned" for exactly how the partitions are allocated. The round robin assignor should distribute them ok.

> will spring issue another poll at this time

Spring has no control - if you are taking too long, the Consumer thread is in the listener - the Consumer is not thread-safe so we can't issue an asynchronous poll.

You **must** process `max.poll.records` within `max.poll.interval.ms` to avoid Kafka from rebalancing the partitions.

The ack mode makes no difference; it's all about processing the results of the poll in a timely fashion.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I meant record not return. thanks for the information. one thing I'm still unclear on how often does spring call the poll() method?  does it call as soon as all the records are processed or on a fixed interval (set to max.poll.interval.ms)

Comment: The thread calls `poll()`, calls the listener with the results (one-at-a-time or the whole batch depending on the listener type); then immediately calls `poll()` again (by default - 2.3 added a new container property `idleBetweenPolls` which is 0 by default).

Comment: Thanks for your response. when you say that same thread calls poll() immediately, will it not wait for the @KafkaListener to finish and acknowledge (with the ack-mode type set to record)  before issuing next poll ? Also how does max.poll.interval.ms comes in to play here ?

Comment: With ack modes other than `RECORD` (e.g. BATCH), before calling the next poll() we commit the offsets; since `syncCommits` is true by default, that call will block until Kafka responds. Then we do the next poll. However, with `AckMode.RECORD` each commit is performed immediately after each record is processed. `max.poll.interval.ms` is the time Kafka allows the consumer to process all the records from the previous poll before considering the consumer to be dead and re-distributing the partitions. The next `poll()` must be called within that time.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your help